# How Do I Use fft() Function In Matlab To Find The Frequency For A Set Of Data Points?

Tags: matlab, fft

I've been given a set of about 20k data points. I managed to import the data into Matlab and did the following :

```
importdata;
fft(importdata);
```

and it returns :

```
Undefined function 'fft' for input arguments of type 'cell'
```

Now, I understand that I need more than this to get it working.

Can someone please tell me any more parameters I need for the `fft` and how to implement it?

**Edit**: These datapoints are timestamps of when something is detected in a machine,
I'm trying to find if there is a period of the detection occuring.

Comment: `fft` requires a vector (or an array) as input. What is the exact type of your data?

Answer (score 1):

Look at the documentation for the correct way to use [`importdata`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/importdata.html) and [`fft`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/fft.html). Both have examples to get you started.

First you need to assign the output of `importdata` to a matrix, then do any data manipulation you need to get it in a form to be used by `fft`. Finally, use `fft` with the correct parameters and compute the correct frequency vector as per the example (obviously, adapted to your data)